# Why is my canvas size not full screen on a PC?

Tags: html, css, canvas, resize

I am making an app, so when a user clicks "Save", the drawing made from the canvas is compiled into an image. This works flawlessly on an iPod Touch:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/du4iC.png

However, when I try it on my Laptop, this happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/39dWC.png

I have tried making the height "auto" and "100%", but I still can't seem to get it working.
Here is a live example:
http:// v1k.me /paint/

Please help me, I am anxious to deploy my app, thank you!

**Here is my code:**

```
<style
type="text/css">body{margin:5px;padding:0}
    canvas{border:1px
    solid
    #999;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;height:
    auto;width:
    auto;}
    a{background-color:#CCC;border:1px
    solid
    #999;color:#333;display:block;height:40px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none}</style>
    <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script
        type="text/javascript">jQuery(window).load(function(){setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,0)},50)});jQuery(function(e){var
            d=e("canvas"),h=e("form").find("input[
            name='u']"),j=e("a"),f=d[0].getContext("2d"),b=null,c=/iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent),g=function(a,c){var
            b=d.offset();return{x:a-b.left,y:c-b.top}},k=function(a){a=c?window.event.targetTouches[0]:a;a=g(a.pageX,a.pageY);b={x:a.x,y:a.y};f.lineTo(b.x,b.y);f.stroke()},l=function(){d.unbind(c?"touchmove":"mousemove");d.unbind(c?"touchend":"mouseup")};j.click(function(a){a.preventDefault();h.val(d[0].toDataURL("image/png"));a=document.getElementById("imgdata").value;document.getElementById("page").innerHTML="
            <center><em><b>Saving...</b> Please wait.</em>
            </center>";e.post("export.php",{u:a},function(a){document.getElementById("page").innerHTML=a})});d.bind(c?"touchstart":"mousedown",function(a){a=c?window.event.targetTouches[0]:a;a=g(a.pageX,a.pageY);b={x:a.x,y:a.y};f.beginPath();f.moveTo(b.x,b.y);d.bind(c?"touchmove":"mousemove",k);d.bind(c?"touchend":"mouseup",l);return!1})});</script>
            <body>
                <div
                id="page"
                align="center">
                    <canvas
                    id="canvas"
                    width="308"
                    height="358"></canvas>
                        <form
                        action="export.php"
                        method="post">
                            <input
                            type="hidden"
                            name="u"
                            id="imgdata"
                            value=""
                            /><a>Save Image</a>
                            </form>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle:
jsfiddle.net/CPPpY/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this inside your code to initialize the canvas object.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth; //document.width is obsolete
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight; //document.height is obsolete
```

Here is a remake of your app with the changes for 100% width and height :)

http://jsfiddle.net/h4CCy/22/

They key changes besides syntax errors are on lines 34 and 35.

Comment: Hmm could you throw this into a Fiddle for me. I literally built something almost identical to this earlier today.

Comment: It is impossible, because I use a POST request to my website. Try this - http://v1k.me/paint/

Comment: No, like it's impossible because of the cross-domain thingy. I will try to make one. And sorry for the obfuscated javascript, I obfuscated it long time ago and didn't get the deobfuscated version, but it's sort of readable?

Comment: I checked out the Fiddle, can you make sure to put iPhone code in there because this app is made just for the iPhones :P

Comment: Ok check the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h4CCy/10/ :) it uses what you wrote with a lot of fixes to syntax errors and automatic resizing to 100%

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xKnOFxK.png This is what I get... And here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CPPpY/1/

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused :/ what exactly are you trying to accomplish? The `canvas` as is in my fiddle will take up all of the available `body` space which was set to like 500px.

Comment: Check it again I fixed that. Or just subtract 60 from desktop versions height modifier.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I was able to use if..else checks on User Agent and set height/width that way. Thanks man!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help, best of luck to the rest of your project :)